# Drupal node needs submit, edit and submit again to fill all data

Tags: drupal

I have a Drupal node form with fields that depend on each other.

1. First field takes data (using default value and tokens) from other fields
2. Second field takes data from the first field

The problem is, that on hitting "save", only first field shows data. To fill second field, I need to hit "edit" and than "save" again.

Is there a way to fill both fields on one "save"?

Will appreciate any guidance.

Comment: With standard Drupal core there is no such thing as dependant fields in an entity/node. So, which contributed modules are you using (CCK framework, custom implementation, ...)? Also, which major version are you on: 6, 7 or 8?

Comment: Rather than using the drupal tag here, consider posting your question directly on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks for answers (I will use dedicated drupal thread from now on).
I'm using Drupal 7. 
The first field is dependent on other because it uses tokens which take data from other fields in this node. 
The second field is a geofield which is taking data (geocoding) from the first field. 
Looking for the way to fill both with data on one "save".